# Docker Desktop Windows - Abysmal performance in AMD system?

Tags: docker-desktop

I've recently assembled a new AMD Desktop, to replace an older Dell Latitude E7540 laptop.

The AMD Desktop:

- Ryzen 3 3100 @ 3.8GHz (4C/8T), 32GB DDR4 3600 CL17 RAM, Corsair P600
  Gen4 SSD

The DELL Laptop:

- Dell Latitude E7540: Intel I7-5600U @ 2.6GHz (2C/4T), 16 MB RAM DDR3 1600, Samsung mSATA PM851

On the new AMD Desktop, when executing a `docker build` command, two situations occur:

- The performance is dreadful, even building a simple image, it takes a long time for the command to start. After starting, it takes a long long time to complete (when it completes)
- The build window crashes almost 50% of the time.

The benchmarks indicate that the new AMD Desktop is 3.5x faster at single core, and 6x faster at multicore.

**As such, I was expecting a much better performance with the new AMD Desktop.**

Unfortunately, that's not the case, and for the same Dockerfile (which generates a very big image):

- The Dell starts faster
- The Dell completes faster (10m vs 30m)
- On the Dell, the build window never crashes.

The only difference between both systems is that one is an Intel platform, the new one an Ryzen 3 AMD.

**Environment Details are the same on both machines:**

- Windows Version: Windows 10 Ent. 19049
- Docker Desktop Version: Docker 3.0.0

**What can explain this abysmal performance on Docker-Desktop on the new AMD system?**

Answer (score 1):

After a few troubling days, i can confirm that the problem is not AMD related.

The culprit is the Antivirus, that when ON, its scanning the files used by Docker, which cause all the problems i've described.

Docker documentation states how to disable the antivirus to scan Docker related files:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/antivirus/

> When antivirus software scans files used by Docker, these files may be locked in a way that causes Docker commands to hang.

> One way to reduce these problems is to add the Docker data directory (/var/lib/docker on Linux, **%ProgramData%\docker** on Windows Server, or $HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/ on Mac) to the antivirus’s exclusion list. However, this comes with the trade-off that viruses or malware in Docker images, writable layers of containers, or volumes are not detected. If you do choose to exclude Docker’s data directory from background virus scanning, you may want to schedule a recurring task that stops Docker, scans the data directory, and restarts Docker.